# Not able to install android apk file even after signed it with my own private key using eclipse

Tags: android

I have created sample android application(apk) and signed it with my private key using eclipse ADT.But i am not able to install it on Android handset(HTC Desire,android version 2.2).

Comment: Check logcat while installing app, you can activate USB debugging mode on HTC device and then connect it to PC. Run command promp on windows and type adb logcat

Answer (score 1):

If you've previously installed the application with a debug certificate, then you have to un-install the old version first since the certificates won't match.

If that isn't it, do you get any errors as to why? Are you installing over adb or from the sdcard (after downloading or otherwise transferring it to the device)?

Comment: Through eclipse Export wizard  I signed my application,then copied it into handset.But after clicking it is not getting install.Initially I haven't installed application with debug certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable third party applications on your device by Settings->Applications, then checking the Unknown sources box?